# wpf toolkit chart axis title location

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

Is there any way to change location and/or orientation of Y-Axis title location in WPF Chart Toolkit ?

I need to move and rotate title like on the picture: 
[Place where I need the rotated title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wl8B.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

Considering you have added the toolkit as:

```
xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

Then adding this inside your /DVC:Chart> control might show similar orientation as in the pic shared:

```
<DVC:Chart.Axes>
            <DVC:LinearAxis Interval="10" Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="True" Title="Pressure (Torr)"/>
            <DVC:LinearAxis Interval="100" Orientation="Y" Location="Top" ShowGridLines="True" Title="Pumping Speed"/>
</DVC:Chart.Axes>
```